# WordPress | Create links + title with custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create links + titles using custom filed.

What do I mean?

For example I have custom filed named: mylink1,mylink2,mylink3 (etc..)

mylink1 value is "Google|http://www.google.com

mylink2 value is "Facebook|http://www.facebook.com"

mylink3 value is "Twitter|http://www.twitter.com"

I want WordPress to display this codes on Single Post theme:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>

<a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
```

I want WordPress to display this code on Single Post theme on every mylinkX custom field value.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, no problem :)

use this code..

```
<?php 

$val = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mylink1', true );

// brake the link on half :)
$desc = substr( $val , 0, strpos($val, '|') ) ;
$href = substr( $val , strpos($val, '|') + 1 ) ;

// in your template show the link with structure!

echo "<a href='" . $$href . "'>" . $desc . "</a>";
```

if the start or end is not correct then index is off, let me know if that works..

Comment: oh.. $$href haha one $ too much :) Thanks!